# Needed date format for milliseconds?

Tags: php, date

We can use the date format in js files for the `day,month,hour,sec` is

`format: 'dHMS'`, and we can use `{hn} {mn} {sn}` in the html file.

I need the same things with the milliseconds also.

i need the `format:''` and the `{}` for html files.

**Following is my code :**

```
<div class="hours-1">
    <p><b>{hn}</b><span><?php echo $language["hr"]; ?></span></p>
</div>
<div class="minitus-1">
    <p><b>{mn}</b><span><?php echo $language["min"]; ?></span></p>
</div>
<div class="seconds-1">
    <p><b>{sn}</b><span><?php echo $language["sec"]; ?></span></p>
</div>' ,onExpiry: liftOff });
```

Comment: Can you copy/paste some code (jsFiddle) to illustrate what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: What date library are you using to convert `{hn}` et al to date parts?

Comment: layout: '<div class="hours-1"><p><b>{hn}</b><span><?php echo $language["hr"]; ?></span></p></div><div class="minitus-1"><p><b>{mn}</b><span><?php echo $language["min"]; ?></span></p></div><div class="seconds-1"><p><b>{sn}</b><span><?php echo $language["sec"]; ?></span></p></div>' ,onExpiry: liftOff  });

Comment: In the js file i have used below things. And they given hn,hnn,mn, mnn for both hour and month. i needed same thing for the millisecond. labels: ['Years', 'Months', 'Weeks', 'Days', 'Hours', 'Minutes', 'Seconds', 'Milliseconds'],
and
compactLabels: ['y', 'm', 'w', 'd', 'ms'],

Comment: layout: '{hn} , {mn}, {sn}, {need for millisecond}

Comment: It seems that you're using some kind of javascript library, but you are providing neither the full code that is used in the page (it's clearly cut off from _something_ at the beginning), nor the name of the library itself. Also, you do not show what you have tried so far to solve the problem.

Comment: i got solution getMilliseconds(); thanks for the comments